# xargs: variable substitution after redirection

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I'm trying to find all text files which have the encoding iso-8859-1 and convert these to UTF-8. My attempt so far is:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep 'iso-8859-1' | cut -d ':' -f1 | 
xargs iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 {} > {}.converted
```

The (obvious) problem is that the last variable substitution won't work, since `{}` occurs after the redirection, and doesn't belong to `xargs`. As is I only get one file called `{}.converted`, not  `a.txt.converted`, `b.txt.converted` etc. How can I make this work?

Note: I'm doing this on Cygwin, where iconv doesn't seem to support `-o`.

Comment: Please have a look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845863/183066).

Comment: I don't know which answer to accept. e.dan and glenn's answers are the most pragmatic, but Ole Tanges is the most esthetically pleasing. chorobas is also quite nice. Have to think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | parallel grep -il iso-8859-1 | parallel iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 {} \> {}.converted
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 2):

How about a `for` loop like:

```
for file in `find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep 'iso-8859-1' | cut -d ':' -f1`; do
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 $file > $file.converted
done
```

Comment: How will your solution deal with the file: `My brother's 12" records: Listed a->z.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming none of your files have newline characters in the name, and assuming you have GNU find and xargs::

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 |
xargs -0 grep -l 'iso-8859-1' |
while read -r file; do
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$file".converted 
done
```

With `grep -l`, you don't need the `cut` command in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep -i iso-8859-1 | cut -f1 -d: | \
xargs -I% echo iconv -f l1 -t utf8 % \> %.utf | bash
```

Comment: How will your solution deal with the file: `My brother's 12" records: Listed a->z.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

echo the command you want xargs to operate on to a string that is piped to the shell and that will overcome the substitution problem.

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep 'iso-8859-1' | cut -d ':' -f1 | 
xargs echo "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 {} > {}.converted" | bash
```