# Process several files with xargs and awk and write the processed data to separate files

Tags: bash, awk, find, output, xargs

I have several files that I want to process with awk and afterwards pipe the outputs of awk to seperate files. I want to process a single file with awk and write the output to a file, but combining that with find and xargs is problematic for me.
This is the current command:

```
find ./*.data -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} awk '/^00/ {printf "Data: %s"$0;}' > {}.processed
```

This only creates a file and combines all processed data by awk into a single file named

> "{}.processed"

.
What is the correct way of writing all output data to separate files?

The filenames of the output for the files "file1.data" and "file2.data" should be:

> file1.data.processed
>   file2.data.processed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use > in an xargs command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845863/how-to-use-in-an-xargs-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `FILENAME` awk Buildin variable for this:

```
 awk '/^00/ {printf "Data: %s",$0 >(FILENAME".processed")}' $(find ./*.data)
```

Comment: That is perfect. I didn't know that awk can actually output to files. I was always assuming it is only responsible for text processing. Thanks Mr. 7171u

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `xargs` you could use a for loop to handle this task:

```
for F in `find ./*.data`; do
   awk '/^00/ {printf "Data: %s"$0;}' "$F" > "$F".processed
done
```