# How to use &>> in a xargs command?

Tags: bash

Experts,

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845863/how-to-use-in-an-xargs-command) I execute this command:

**xargs argument using posix:**

```
find <somePath> -name '*.html' | sort -n | xargs -I{} sh -c 'w3m "{}" &>> "test.log"' --{}
```

I get the following errors:

- file.hml: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
- file.hml: -c: line 0: `w3m ".html" &>> "test.log"'

Why does bash not understand &>> in my line execution?

As @Nahuel Fouilleul said "sh (posix) doesn't recognize the (bash) redirection &>>".

**xargs argument using bash**

However the solution proposed is not working when I execute the following command:

```
find <somePath> -name '*.html' | sort -n | xargs -I{} w3m {} &>> "test.log"
```

I receive this error:

- bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'

Why does bash not understand &>> in my line execution? See my answer

Comment: Do you replace <somePath> by some path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may not work if `sh` (posix) doesn't recognize the (bash) redirection `&>>`.
but the command still can break for certain file names.

Command should be.

```
.. | xargs -I{} bash -c 'w3m "$1" &>> "test.log"' "process_name_you_want" {}
```

or to avoid to open log file for each file redirection can be moved out

```
.. | xargs -I{} w3m {} &>> "test.log"
```

EDIT: answer is general to a tool which processes files and write to output, after looking at w3m tool it seems it's a web browser in a console, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks
I tried the second solution ".. | xargs -I{} w3m {} &>> "test.log" and I receive the following error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'.
I have html files in a directory and I would like to dump them in a log file. Therefore I use w3m that displays the information of the html file in the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170572/what-is-in-a-shell-script) I realized that the operator "&>>" is only available from **Bash version 4**. I am using **Bash version 3.2.51** so it doesn't work.

For versions previous to bash 4 two operators are needed:

```
w3m >> test.log 2>&1
```

where:

">>" append stdout to test.log

"2>&1" redirect the stderr to where the sdout is going

So the command working with xargs is the following:

```
.. | xargs -I{} w3m {} >> "test.log" 2>&1
```