# Redirect logs of pods in my k8s to a file with pod name

Tags: linux, shell, kubernetes

I was trying to redirect logs of pods in a k8s into a file of their name.

`kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1}' | tail -2 | xargs -I {} kubectl logs {} > {}`

This is the result.

`demo@demo1:~/log$ ls
{}`

What I need is, if this is the pod details

`demo@demo1:~/log$ kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod1                              1/1     Running     0          3d23h
pod2                              1/1     Running     0          3d23h`

The expected result is

`demo@demo1:~/log$ ls
pod1  pod2`

files pod1 & pod2 will have logs of respective pods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'kubectl logs $1 > $1' -- {}
```

Courtesy to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845863/how-to-use-in-an-xargs-command)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(kubectl get po -oname | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'); do kubectl logs $i > $i; done
```