# How to run a command that only takes 1 arg with multiple args and redirect stdout?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to run this command called `codemaker` which takes a filename as input but then writes the output to stdout instead of back to the file, so I have to redirect stdout to that file. That works fine, but I want to do this for a whole bunch of files at once, so I came up with this (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/845928/65387):

```
ctouch() {
  xargs -t -i -0 sh -c 'codemaker "$1" > "$1"' -- {} <<<"${(ps:\0:)@}"
}
```

But I can't quite get the syntax right. It looks like it's treating everything as a single arg still:

```
❯ ctouch foo.h bar.cc                                                                                                      
sh -c 'codemaker "$1" > "$1"' -- 'foo.h bar.cc'$'\n'
```

Whereas I just want to run 2 commands:

```
codemaker foo.h > foo.h
codemaker bar.cc > bar.cc
```

How do I make an alias/function for that?

(And no, I'm not sure about that `<<<"${(ps:\0:)@}"` bit either. Really hard to Google. I want the usual `"$@"` to expand with null separators to feed to `xargs`)

Comment: Does `codemaker foo.h > foo.h` actually work? Wouldn't that clobber the input file before the program even runs?

Comment: @rowboat There is no input file actually, `foo.h` doesn't exist prior. `codemaker` needs a filepath because it will generate different things based on the path/filename and the extension.

Comment: Why don't you loop over the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a compelling reason to use `xargs` in your case. You just create additional processes unnecessarily (one for `xargs`, plus for each argument, one shell process).

A simpler solution (and IMO easier to understand) would be to do it with this zsh-function:

```
ctouch() {
  for f
  do
    codemaker $f >$f
  done
}
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't even think of that  xargs can run stuff in parallel but performance isn't an issue here.

Comment: It can, but in the way you used `xargs`, you let it process the arguments sequentially. That's why I did not think that you wanted parallelism. BTW, you can also parallelize the loop, by running `codemaker` in the background. Another, more flexible, approach would be to use [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). We use `xargs` mainly for cases, where the command to be invoked allows for an _arbitrary number_ of arguments, and we want to feed to each invocation as many arguments as can fit into the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a lot easier to just do with `printf`.

```
ctouch() {
  printf -- '%s\0' "$@" | xargs -t -i -0 sh -c 'codemaker "$1" > "$1"' -- {}
}
```